# How to animate view inside popupwindow before dismissing popup window in android?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I want to animate the view inside the popup window before dismissing it. So i have animated the view inside the dismiss listener like below,

```
penPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TranslateAnimation animateSlideUp = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0, mImageViewLike.getHeight());
                        animateSlideUp.setDuration(200);
                        animateSlideUp.setFillAfter(true);
                        mImageViewLike.startAnimation(animateSlideUp);
                        mImageViewLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 200);

            }
        });
```

But this will not animate the imageview inside the popup window before closing the popup window and setOnDismissListener not called before closing the popup window. Could you please suggest me an idea to do any action before closing the popupwindow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you put delay of 200?

Comment: The animation must start after some delay. But in my case the control not goes inside setOnDismissListener @ Nisarg

Comment: @Sangeetha are you dismissing them on any click?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you should do it,

1)Create Two Different set of animations.

say, `popup_show.xml` and `popup_hide.xml` and add it to your anim folder which you have to create inside res folder.

2)Now inside values folder create a xml called `styles.xml` and add these animations to it like this,

```
<style name="Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
</style>
```

3)Now set this style to your PopupWindow animation,

```
popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
```

Now it automatically detects Window Enter and Exit and provides with the required animation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to animate the image which placed inside the popup window. I do not want to animate my popup window. But in my case dismiss listener not called while closing the popup window. could you please suggest me an idea. Why the dismiss listener not detecting? @ shridutt kothari

Comment: PopupWindow.OnDismissListener is helpfull when you want to do something after popup dismiss, so as you are trying to animate some image inside after PopupWindow.OnDismiss, its not gonna work as at that time popup is already dismissed.

Comment: okay. How can i do some animation before closing the popup window. Is there any way to achieve it? @ shridutt kothari

Answer (score 2):

If you start the animation `on popup dismiss` then where you do the animation?.

You should do it in inverse way.

Start the `animation` and when `animation end` then `dismiss` the `dialog.`

```
        TranslateAnimation animateSlideUp = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0, mImageViewLike.getHeight());
        animateSlideUp.setDuration(200);
        animateSlideUp.setFillAfter(true);
        mImageViewLike.startAnimation(animateSlideUp);
        animateSlideUp.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                penPopupWindow.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will add animation listener in my code. And i do not want to close the popup window after animation ends. I need to animate the view before closing the popup window.@Sohail Zahid

Comment: @Sangeetha you can comment the the code as your needs.

Comment: @Sangeetha if the post help please tick mark and vote up.happy coding

Answer (score 2):

> any action before closing the popupwindow?

You can extend PopupWindow and override dismiss method. Then you can call dismiss animation before super.

```
public class SomeClass extends PopupWindow {

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {

        //TODO: animation here

        super.dismiss();
    }
}
```